# VLCJ: Time code missing when saving a video stream from an embedded media player

Tags: libvlc, vlcj

I have an application that shows a video stream from a camera, and is able to save the video stream on a file on request. When I run this command from the terminal I see the video in VLC, and the contents is saved on a file as expected:

```
vlc v4l:///dev/video0:norm=ntsc ':sout=#duplicate{dst=display{noaudio},dst="transcode{vcodec=wmv2,vb=800}:file{dst=aaa.wmv}"}'
```

However, when I save a file from my application the there are no time codes in the file, so when I open the file in another application I'm unable to move backwards or forwards in the file. I can also not see how long the file is.

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
mainframe = new JFrame("Video Viewer");
fullscreenStrategy = new DefaultFullScreenStrategy(mainframe);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
EmbeddedMediaPlayer player= factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(fullscreenStrategy);
mainframe.add(canvas);
player.setVideoSurface(factory.newVideoSurface(canvas));
...
String media = "v4l:///dev/video0:norm=ntsc";
String filename = "aaa.wmv";
String mediaoptions = ":sout=#duplicate{ dst=display,"+
" dst=\"transcode{vcodec=wmv2,vb=800}:"+
"file{dst="+filename+"}\"}");
player.prepareMedia(media, mediaoptions);
player.start();
```

aaa.wmv is created, but without time codes.

What can be wrong? The only difference I see from the command line version is that I use a Canvas widget with the EmbeddedMediaPlayer instead of the native VLC view window.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the problem. For the time codes to be saved properly it is necessary to call player.release(). I did that, but before the release call I copied the file to another location. Since release hadn't been called yet the file was incomplete. When I changed the code to first call player.release(), then copy the file it worked as expected.